# Replace user defined string between a decimal number in c# using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string with decimal numbers. For some other reason, I want to replace a character instead of "." between the decimal number.

For example,

```
string str="SAIF Partners had invested $22.5 million in 2006."
```

What I need is, I want to replace a character between the $22.5 like this $22r!5. 
So my final string would be like this,

```
string final="SAIF Partners had invested $22r!5 million in 2006."
```

how can I achieve this? Any help would be really appreciated.

I tried the below code. But I think I am missing something.

```
  string final= Regex.Replace(str, @"[^\D]+", "r!");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = "SAIF Partners had invested $22.5 million in 2006.";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d+)(\.)(\d+)", "$1r!$3");
```

Comment: Please add more description to the answer, code-only answers are not welcome. Adding explanation usually result in more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)
```

Use `lookarounds`.See demo.Replace by `r!` or `whatever characters you want to put`

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/12

`var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)", "r!");`